# Picture not displaying on IE !

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, url

I have a laughing problem : I upload a picture on my server.

This image is displaying on Firefox, but not on IE, why ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) image. IE can handle only RGB images.

Tell the person responsible for the image to set the colour space to RGB in their Photoshop (CS3 on Windows, to be precise :P ) before saving the file.